# Currying a sum of squares function in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, computer-science, currying

I am trying to curry a functions of 4 arguments in Scheme. This is what I have for my `curry` function. The output should be 30. Please help me with my `curry4` function.

```
(define sum-of-squares
  (lambda (a b c d)
    (+ (* a a) (* b b) (* c c) (* d d))))

(define curry4
  (lambda (a b c d)
    (apply sum-of-squares (a (b (c (d)))))))

(((((curry4 sum-of-squares) 1) 2) 3) 4)
```

Comment: It'd be better to take a list instead of a fixed number of arguments... is this for a class or something?

Comment: It is practice problems

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you can try:

```lisp
(define (((((curry-4 func) a) b) c) d)
  (func a b c d))
```

Note that this is special syntax for expanding it out like:

```lisp
(define (curry-4 func)
  (λ (a)
    (λ (b)
      (λ (c)
        (λ (d) (func a b c d))))))
```

What we're doing here is returning a lambda that returns a lambda that ... returns a lambda that returns the result of applying `func`. Essentially, we're taking one argument at a time, and once we have all of them, we can give back the final value. Until then, we give back a function that's still waiting for the rest of the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In Racket just use `curry`. You can check definining file in DrRacket.

```
#lang racket
(define (f n1 n2 n3 n4)
  (apply +
         (map (λ (x) (expt x 2))
              (list n1 n2 n3 n4))))

(((((curry f) 1) 2) 3) 4)
```

Currying by hand.

```
#lang racket
(define curry-by-hand-f
  (lambda (x1)
    (lambda (x2)
      (lambda (x3)
        (lambda (x4)
          (f x1 x2 x3 x4))))))

((((curry-by-hand-f 1) 2) 3) 4)
```

Comment: This doesn't provide a general purpose `curry-4` function so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @MLavrentyev it does now.